# Trying to select an element class inside a template literal and once i declared it using the DOM manipulation keep getting not defined on my console

Tags: javascript, dom-events, closures, dom-manipulation, template-literals

I am trying to select the element class inside the template literals and also make them available to be     use outside the `eventListener`:

```
addToCart.addEventListener('click', (e) =>  {
    let cartButton = e.currentTarget;
    let price = cartButton.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].children[0].children
    let name = cartButton.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[1].textContent.trim();
    let image = cartButton.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].src;
    let position = image.indexOf("images");
    let partPath = image.slice(position);
    const shopping = {};
    shopping.img = partPath;
    shopping.name = name;
    shopping.price = price;

    const cartInfo = document.createElement('div');
    cartInfo.classList.add('carted-items');
    cartInfo.innerHTML =`<figure class="carted-image">
                <img src="${shopping.img}" alt="carted image" class="carted-img">
            </figure>
            <div class="carted-info">
                <h4 class="carted-name">${shopping.name}</h4>
                <div class="quan-price">
                    <span class="carted-quantity">$${shopping.price} * <span class = "number-of-items">3         </span</span>
                    <span class="carted-price">$375.00</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <figure class="delete-image">
                <img src="./images/icon-delete.svg" alt="delete button" class="delete-img">
            </figure>`

cartContent.insertBefore(cartInfo, checkOut);
alert("item added to the cart"); 

});
```

Comment: Off topic: Please don't use code like `parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].children[0]` in real code. Instead, give the ancestor a class and use `closest('.className')`, then select the children using `querySelector` (e.g., `.querySelector('.classUniqueToChildren3')`).

Comment: Thanks but i want to achieve there is once the cart button is been clicked i want it to grab those specific element alongside with it

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable to be available outside the scope of the function, declare it outside the function:

```
let cartButton
addToCart.addEventListener('click', (e) =>  {
    cartButton = e.currentTarget;
    let price = cartButton.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children[3].children[0].children
});

console.log(cartButton) // cartButton is available, price is not.
```

Comment: Thank you @lee but what my problem is how i'm going to select those class inside that template literals and do some manipulation on it like cosnt me = document.querryselector('. delete-img'); and also make them readily available to be use outside that eventListener